# The meaning of "minking it"

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang

There's a line in the musical *Guys and Dolls*:

> When you see a Joe saving half of his dough,
>
> You can bet he'll be **minking it** for some doll.

My initial instinct is that this is a verbification of "mink" as in jackets or coats (the Joe is spending his money on mink furs for 'some doll'). Is this a reasonable interpretation or does *minking it* impart some sort of regional slang meaning beyond that? The musical is set mostly in New York during the 1930s.

Comment: During the 1920s, I think--the prohibition era. Damon Runyon's stories are often of bootleggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are merely mistaken in the lyric. Some transcriptions show the following instead:

> When you see a Joe, saving half of his dough,
>   You can bet they’ll be minting it for some doll,

See [here](http://www.thepeaches.com/music/frank/GuysandDolls.htm) and [here](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/franksinatra/guysanddolls.html) for this version.

Another and even more likely-sounding version is “there’ll be mink in it for some doll,” on which see [here](http://www.songlyrics.com/guys-and-dolls/guys-and-dolls-lyrics/) and [here](http://musicals.lyricsallsongs.com/guys-and-dolls/guys-and-dolls.html).

Comment: The "mink in it" does seem to be correct, it's the only one I could find in published writing once I knew what to look for: http://books.google.com/books?id=tdjLAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT392&dq=%22When+you+see+a+Joe+saving+half+of+his+dough%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lTefU-DVE8vMsQTOyoK4Bw&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22When%20you%20see%20a%20Joe%20saving%20half%20of%20his%20dough%22&f=false

Answer (score 3):

I think the line goes "You can bet there'll be mink in it for some doll". So you got the sense right even if the lyric is different.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the original person who said it refers to getting a mink coat for his doll.  I grew up in a very similar environment as described in "Guys and Dolls".  For example at my "Stag" when I got married in the 1960s, in addition to the stripper and steak dinner at the event, there was a "floating" craps game (of course illegal).  I should also mention that my mother always wanted a mink coat (it had to be "mink"), which my father (a truck driver) eventually had a "fence" come to where we lived with several relatives, with many mink coats that my mother picked one that my father bought from him (recall the song in Guys and Dolls entitled "Take Back Your Mink" and the line in it referring to the "old worn out pelts").